# Showing previous tasks outcome on same page

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a 3 step workflow using "Collect Feedback" in SPD. In first steps it goes to user1, then to user2 and then user3.

It shows same form to each user which contain following fields:

1. Favourite color
2. Favourite movie

I have actually customized this default "Collect Feedback" form in InfoPath by deleting all fields and only showing the above two. It is working fine.

When workflow comes to user2, I want to display values submitted by user1 on that same form. And when it goes to user3, I want to show values submitted by both user1 and user2 on the form being displayed to user3.

How can I do this?

SharePoint, SPD and InfoPath are 2013 while workflow is based on 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I can think off is to have a master list for the workflow to run on and then a related list with reference to current item of the master list and the current approver.

Capture all relevant data in the related list. This way you can show individual's choices for common fields to the current user.

**Update**

You may have to figure how to add entry into the related list from the master list form. May be have all common fields in the master too, just copy over the values in workflow before logic movies to next user for input.